# How to create the waved style for curves in Graphics?

Tags: plotting, graphics, style

There are the `dashed` and `dotted` styles for lines and circles when we plot them with `Graphics`. For example, `Graphics[{Dashed, Line[{{1, 0}, {2, 1}}]}]`. Is it possible to construct the line or circle with `wave` instead of `dash` or `dot`? That is, `Graphics[{Waved, Line[{{1, 0}, {2, 1}}]}]` will produce

[image]

and `Graphics[{Waved, Circle[{0, 0}, 1]}]` will produce

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can try using Sin[x] while plotting? I'm pretty sure you have to change something to do this

Comment: [Maybe related.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11355/38178)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not a complete answer.

You can make use of the undocumented function `` Typeset`MakeBoxes `` mentioned in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/27209/1871). Here I'll just code waved line and circle as examples:

```
(* Stolen from Simon's post, notice the tiny modification. *)
SetAttributes[createPrimitive, HoldAll]
createPrimitive[patt_, expr_] := 
 Typeset`MakeBoxes[p : patt, fmt_, Graphics] := 
  With[{e = Cases[expr, Line[_], Infinity]}, 
   Typeset`MakeBoxes[Interpretation[e, p], fmt, Graphics]]

createPrimitive[Waved[a_, f_, pts_: Automatic]@Circle[p : {x0_, y0_} : {0, 0}, r0_: 1], 
 ParametricPlot[{x0 + Cos[t] (r0 + a Sin[f t]), y0 + Sin[t] (r0 + a Sin[f t])}, {t, 0, 
   2 Pi}, PlotPoints -> pts]]

createPrimitive[Waved[a_, f_, pts_: Automatic]@Line[p : {{_, _?NumericQ} ..}], 
 Module[{fx, fy, 
   distance = Prepend[Accumulate@Sqrt[Total@Transpose@((Rest@# - Most@# &@N@p)^2)], 0.], 
   normal}, {fx, fy} = 
   ListInterpolation[#, distance, InterpolationOrder -> 1] & /@ Transpose@N@p; 
  normal = Sqrt[fx'[t]^2 + fy'[t]^2]; 
  ParametricPlot[{fx@t + a Sin[f t] fy'[t]/normal, fy@t - a Sin[f t] fx'[t]/normal}, {t, 
    0, distance[[-1]]}, PlotPoints -> pts]]]
```

Usage:

```
Graphics[{Red, Thick, Waved[1/50, 40]@Line[{{1, 0}, {2, 1}, {3, -1}, {4, 0}}], Orange, 
  Waved[1/10, 50, 51]@Circle[{2.5, 0}, 3/2]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

## Remaining Issues

1. The achieved syntax is slightly different from the expected one, not sure if the expected syntax can be achieved with `` Typeset`MakeBoxes ``.
2. The waved style is coded separately for every graphics primitive, so creating a complete waved style still requires huge amount of work.
3. `ParametricPlot` is relatively slow.
4. The wave doesn't look great at corners:

   ```
    Graphics[{Red, Thick, Waved[1/10, 40]@Line[{{1, 0}, {2, 1}, {3, 0}}]}]
   ```

   [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: That does not work on Graphs, e.g. `Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, Style[3 <-> 1, Waved[1/10, 40]]}]` does not work. Any idea on how to extend it so that it can be used to style edges in a graph?

Comment: @Pueggel I'm not familiar with `Graph`, but `EdgeShapeFunction` seems to be your friend: `ef[pts_List, e_] :=
 Waved[1/50, 40]@Line[pts]; Graph[{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 1}, 
 EdgeShapeFunction -> ef]`

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to make ondulations on a BSpline.

Here is a toy example with a closed BSpline ("closed" in order to see the continuity at the ends)

```
p={{15.7336, -3.557}, {11.1177, -2.53343}, {15.4259, 19.1467},
   {6.60292, 10.5131},{-28.5053, 10.9099}, {-22.7909, -1.35239},
   {-3.22756, -13.0483},{-17.1309, -32.426}, {6.23965, -7.05847},
   {25.0532, -25.0634}};

f = BSplineFunction[p, SplineClosed -> True];  

Show[ParametricPlot[f[x], {x, 0, 1}]]
```

[image]

```
absCurv=NDSolveValue[{abcCurv'[x]==Norm[f'[x]],abcCurv[0]==0},{abcCurv},{x,0,1}][[1]];  

length=absCurv[1];

numberOfTurns = 50;

f1[x_]=f[x] - Sin[2 Pi numberOfTurns absCurv[x]/length]  {{0,1}, {-1,0}}.Normalize[f'[x]];

ParametricPlot[f1[x],{x,0,1},PlotPoints-> 1000]
```

[image]

[inspiration source 1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/146457/5467)   (about `{{0,1}, {-1,0}}.Normalize[f'[x]]`)
[inspiration source 2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138173/5467) (about `absCurv=NDSolveValue[...`)